# How to remove a string from a line

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I am working on a property file containing list of Users: For Example

```
JFR=abc1@abc.com,abc2@abc.com
UserListApp1=abc1@abc.com,abc2@abc.com
UserListApp2=abc1@abc.com
AdminList=abc1@abc.com
GlobalList=abc1@abc.com
```

Now, In case I just want to remove abc1@abc.com only from AdminList. How can we do it from Linux using sed or awk?
I am new to linux please help

EDIT:
I don't want to delete the whole value part. I just want to delete the specific string. For Example if my file looks like :

```
JFR=abc1@abc.com,abc2@abc.com
UserListApp1=abc1@abc.com,abc2@abc.com
UserListApp2=abc1@abc.com
AdminList=abc1@abc.com,abc2@abc.com,abc3@abc.com,abc4@abc.com
GlobalList=abc1@abc.com
```

In this case I just want to get rid of abc1@abc.com from AdminList

Comment: This looks familiar, but I can't yet find a previous version of this question.  Could the email address exist at any point in the list -- beginning, middle, or end? What should an empty list look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Case 1: Remove complete "value" part

Assuming your file only contains "simple" `key=value` statements, i.e. such that the "value" part contains *no* `=` sign, you can use `sed` as follows:

```
sed '/^AdminList/s/=.*$/=/' propertyfile.txt
```

Output for your example would look like:

```
JFR=abc1@abc.com,abc2@abc.com
UserListApp1=abc1@abc.com,abc2@abc.com
UserListApp2=abc1@abc.com
AdminList=
GlobalList=abc1@abc.com
```

The idea here is to substitute (the `s` in the command) the expression consisting of `=`, followed by any number of characters (the `.*` part) up to the end of line (the `$` symbol), with a simple `=`, but only on lines starting with `AdminList`.

#### Case 2: Excise specific value from value list

If you want to remove only one specific value from a comma-separated list, I would recommend an `awk`-based approach:

```
awk '/^AdminList/ {sub(/abc1@abc.com,?/,""); print;next} {print}' propertyfile.txt
```

This would match the line starting with `AdminList` and replace the pattern `abc1@abc.com`, possibly with a trailing `,` with the empty string, print the modified line, and skip execution to the next line. For all other lines, it will simply print the entire line.

Given your second example input, this produces:

```
JFR=abc1@abc.com,abc2@abc.com
UserListApp1=abc1@abc.com,abc2@abc.com
UserListApp2=abc1@abc.com
AdminList=abc2@abc.com,abc3@abc.com,abc4@abc.com
GlobalList=abc1@abc.com
```

The syntax chosen should be fairly portable; I have tested it with GNU Awk and Mawk.

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I was looking for. You're right if we want to remove the last entry there would be a trailing ",". Thanks for the quick help! Appretiate it.

Answer (score 0):

Save your data in file(for test) test.txt

```
JFR=abc1@abc.com,abc2@abc.com
UserListApp1=abc1@abc.com,abc2@abc.com
UserListApp2=abc1@abc.com
AdminList=abc1@abc.com
GlobalList=abc1@abc.com
```

And use sed or grep

```
cat test.txt | sed /AdminList/d
cat test.txt | grep -v AdminList
```

Edit:

```
cat test.txt | grep AdminList | awk -F"=" '{print $2}' | sed -n 1'p' | tr ',' '\n' | while read word; do if [ "$word" = "abc1@abc.com" ]; then continue; else echo $word; fi; done
```

Comment: This would just delete the line containing `AdminList` entirely, but I think the OP wants to keep the "key" part, so that the desired output looks like `AdminList=` for that line.

Answer (score 0):

To edit the file directly with sed, use

```
sed -i '/AdminList=abc1@abc.com/d' file
```

Answer (score 0):

command

```
sed "/AdminList/s/abc1\@abc\.com,//g"  filename
```

input

```
JFR=abc1@abc.com,abc2@abc.com
UserListApp1=abc1@abc.com,abc2@abc.com
UserListApp2=abc1@abc.com
AdminList=abc1@abc.com,abc2@abc.com,abc3@abc.com,abc4@abc.com
GlobalList=abc1@abc.com
```

output

```
JFR=abc1@abc.com,abc2@abc.com
UserListApp1=abc1@abc.com,abc2@abc.com
UserListApp2=abc1@abc.com
AdminList=,abc2@abc.com,abc3@abc.com,abc4@abc.com
GlobalList=abc1@abc.com
```

Comment: That looks very good, but you may want to provide for the trailing `,` by using `/abc1\@abc\.com,\?/`.

Comment: Corrected @AdminBee